# ¿Que ocurre si asigno null al identificador de una expresión de función dentro de la propia función?

Tags: javascript

Creo que no tiene sentido hacerlo, tampoco obtengo ningún error.

Me gustaria saber ¿que ocurre cuando lo hago?, la funcion se esta ejecutando y desreferenciarla mientras lo hace ¿no deberia dar error porque desreferenciarla seria como de repente no tener nada que ejecutar?

```
(function foo(){ 
  foo=null
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código se encuentra en un scope autoejecutable, aquello que tienes pasa porque al crearse una funcion se crea una "cola de instrucciones", las cuales deben ser ejecutadas cuando la función sea ejecutada por nosotros.

Puedes verlo como si enrealidad la función es "la plantilla" y el cuerpo de la función son los procesos que hay dentro de ella.

Digamos que al destruir la función no estas destruyendo los procesos que hay en cola (en memoria), si no que mas bien destruyes el cuerpo de la plantilla (lo conviertes a null), haciendo que aunque la plantilla ya no exista, aquellos procesos que estén en memoria sigan existiendo hasta que sean ejecutados.

Una vez ejecutados estos procesos serán destruidos, quedando libre esa cola de procesos y apartir de ese momento ya la referencia de esa función no existira ni tampoco los procesos que la sostenían.

Es como crear el molde para hacer un vaso de cristal y que mientras el vaso se este calentando, en algún momento quitarle el molde, el vaso que tenemos al ya haberse endurecido lo suficiente no requerirá mas del molde, pero aquellos procesos que requieren para terminarlo seguirán ejecutándose hasta que el molde este terminado.

Es por este motivo que la funcion `foo` que tienes no da error alguno al quitarle su referencia en tiempo de ejecución.

Pero veamos que pasa si sacamos tu función del scope que tienes y luego intentamos ejecutarla por segunda vez:

```js
function foo(){ 
  foo=null
  console.log("Hola! dentro de foo!");
  console.log("Todo correcto dentro de foo!");
}

foo();
foo();
```

El resultado ahora si es un `error`, la primera vez no, por la cola de procesos almacenada, la cual permite que el cuerpo de la función pueda seguirse ejecutando aunque su referencia haya sido destruida.

La segunda vez esa referencia a la funcion `foo` ya no existe por este motivo da error, no tenemos "el molde" que nos ayuda a crear la cola de procesos en ese instante.